# Why do we stop after reaching this term? Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, reduction

I'm calculating the normal form of a lambda Term. I also have the solution so I know that my steps until the "end" were right.
The given term is

```
(\a.\b.(\x.a b x)(\y. b y x) a) (\f. f f)g
```

and the normalform of that is

```
    g g (\y. g y x)(\f. f f)
```

I also got this but then I continued and I do not understand why this is the final term. I continued with

```
g g g (\f. f f) x
```

and then

```
g g g x x
```

But apparently I went too far, do you know why you are supposed to stop earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a matter of stopping earlier. You're misinterpreting the syntax of lambda calculus.

By convention, when we write `A B C`, we mean `(A B) C`, not `A (B C)`; that is, [function application is left associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus_definition#Notation).

Therefore

```
g g (\y. g y x)(\f. f f)
```

parses as

```
((g g) (\y. (g y) x)) (\f. f f)
```

In particular, `(g g)` is applied to `(\y. g y x)`, whereas `(\y. g y x)` is *not* applied to `(\f. f f)`.